# Making an approximation

Tags: binomial-theorem, approximation-theory

How does $\sqrt{\frac{2(cos(x)-1)}{cos(x)}} \approx x$?

At first I thought it was an example of binomial approximation but I was unable to approximate is to just $x$. I could only get $$\left(\frac{2cos(x)}{cos(x)}-\frac{2}{cos(x)}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ 
$$\left(2-\frac{2}{cos(x)}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \approx 2-\frac{1}{cos(x)}$$

Am I using the binomial approximation theorem correctly? Or is there another way of approximating this value?

Comment: $\cos(x)= 1- x^2/2 + \cdots$

Comment: Is it in a neighbourhood of $0$? Then the radicand is negative.

Comment: I think you have a sign problem.  For $x$ near $0$ your expression is imaginary.  Perhaps you meant $1-\cos x$ in the numerator?

Comment: @lulu unfortunatly no, it is $cos(x)-1$

Comment: You sure about that? FWIW, $\sqrt{\frac{2(1 - \cos(x))}{\cos(x)}}$ is quite close to $x$ for $0 < 0.5$. And it also works for negative $x$ if you take the negative square root. Eg $f(0.1) \approx 0.100209$, $f(0.4) \approx  0.4140$.

Comment: @PM2Ring I have double checked and it is $cos(x)-1$

Comment: No, really, what you wrote down is not correct.  Try it for small positive values of $x$.  With the sign change I proposed you get $|x|$ for small $x$.

Comment: With all due respect, the source you checked is wrong, I suspect a typo. $\cos x \le 1$ for all real $x$, so $\cos x - 1$ _has_ to be negative. And so unless $x$ is an angle in the left half of the plane where $\cos$ is negative, making the denominator negative as well, the quantity under the square root is negative.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try and the legitimacy of the source and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near $0$?

Well, first of all you have a sign error.  For small $x\neq 0$ we have  $0<\cos x<1$ so the expression inside the radical is clearly negative.  Accordingly, I believe you are trying to show that $$\sqrt {2\,\frac {1-\cos x}{\cos x}}\approx |x|$$ for $x$ near $0$.  At least, this has the advantage of being true.

To see it, note that  $$\cos x \approx 1 -\frac {x^2}2\implies \frac 1{\cos x}\approx1+\frac {x^2}2$$  Here the second approximation follows from the first by means of first stage of the Geometric series $\frac 1{1-z}\approx 1+z$.

It follows that  the modified  expression is approximately $$\sqrt {2\times \left(1+\frac {x^2}2\right)\times \frac {x^2}2}\approx \sqrt {x^2+\frac {x^4}2}\approx |x|$$

Comment: The jump from$$\cos x\approx\dots$$to$$\frac1{\cos x}\approx\dots$$is probably not immediately clear.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  Thanks, I'll add a sentence.